# Custom data freshness options for own connector

Tags: looker-studio

I'm building a new Data Studio connector where I want to define data freshness options rather than only the default 12 hour option. Is it possible to do it?

**Currently**:

[image: Currently]

**Expected**:

[image: Expected]

Answer (score 2):

This feature is not currently available right now for Community Connectors(Jun 2020). However, you can make a feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=345845&template=1162971).

Answer (score 0):

You will see similar options once your data sources are verified by Looker and published.
Unpublished data connectors have by default 12 Hour freshness.